# swiftの関数(引数)について

Tags: swift

Myplaygroundでの練習でのことです。(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXHAv.jpg)
まだswiftでのプログラミングの文法を始めたばかりで基本中の基本なんですが、なぜエラーが出るのかわかりません。

Comment: http://qiita.com/kakipo/items/061ef0d661ed1260c2ef
当該エラーでググると出てきましたけどこれじゃない？

Comment: @豚吐露 トピックは正しいですが、その記事はSwift 2の仕様に基づいて書かれているのでそれに従うと同じエラーになってしまいます。

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2からSwift 3に変わった際に関数の呼び出し規約が変更になりました。Swift 2では第一引数に限り引数名のラベルはデフォルトで省略されるという挙動でしたが（Objective-Cの命名規約に近くなるようにしていた）Swift 3では文法上の一貫性を優先するために、最初の引数であっても外部引数名のラベルをつけて呼び出すことが必要になりました。

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md

つまり、`areaOfTrianbleWithBase(3, andHeight: 4)`はSwift 2では正しいですが、Swift 3ではコンパイルエラーになります。

正しくは第一引数にも外部引数名のラベルを付加して次のように呼び出します。

```
areaOfTrianbleWithBase(base: 3, andHeight: 4)
```